# remove everything but alphanumeric and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that has some special characters and spaces. I can remove the special characters, but how can I make it so it keeps the spaces?

```
var a = "dent's dc^e co cbs";

var re = /\W/g;

b = a.replace(re, '');

console.log(b);
```

The way it is, it just deletes everything. And it broke when I tried to add `(^\s)` after the `W`

Comment: Note: `\s` does not match only space, it matches all white space characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negated character class with `\w`, and `\s`:

```
var re = /[^\w ]/g;
```

- `[^\w]` gives you same effect as `\W`
- Addition of an empty space `" "` in negated character class, also negates space.

Comment: so that's a literal space after the `\w`? doesn't that negation apply to the alphanumeric characters as well due to the \w?

Comment: @thomas. Yes it's a literal space. And yes the negation apply to alphanumeric character as well. And that is what `\W` too do. It matches everything except alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @thomas. So this will remove everything except alphanumeric characters and space.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` doesn't contain numbers. Use this regex: `/[^0-9A-Za-z ]/`
It matches every char except numbers, capital and non capital letters and the space.